# Get last child of div in Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am taking a fairly simple piece of code and wrapping into a function, the code builds a slide out menu from the items inside a div.  I'm now trying to get the last child from a div:

```
experimentOne('#experimentOne');

   function experimentOne(masterContainer) {
   var experimentOneMenuButton = $('masterContainer :last-child');
   ... etc
```

However, this returns [] in the log.  When I check the width, instead of the 100px it should be, it's 1420 which I'm guessing is the window width.

If I just get the last child of the ID by coding it in everything is fine, but I want the function to be as reusable as possible.

Thanks.

Comment: If 'masterContainer' is supposed to be an id then `$('#'+ masterContainer +' :last-child');`

Comment: Although in this case it's probably that `'masterContainer :last-child'` should be `masterContainer+' :last-child'`, or even better `$( masterContainer ).children().last()`

Comment: what your function expects the 'masterContainer' to be ? string ? HTMLElementObject ?

Comment: var experimentOneMenuButton = $(masterContainer).children().last();  works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this if your masterContainer is an element:

```
var experimentOneMenuButton = $(':last-child', masterContainer);
```

Or this if it is a string for the element id

```
var experimentOneMenuButton = $('#'+masterContainer+' :last-child');
```

Answer (score 1):

`masterContainer` is a variable containing the value of the parent container, so when you build the selector you need use it with string concatenation.

```
var experimentOneMenuButton = $(masterContainer + ' :last-child');
```

or you can use a context based lookup

```
var experimentOneMenuButton = $(':last-child', masterContainer);
```

I would recommend the second solution which make use of context bases lookup since it is neater.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fF4MX/)

Answer (score 1):

- element with id is selected with "#"
- you need to target immediat children with ">", [space] target all descendants of element

  `$('#masterContainer>:last-child');`

Answer (score 0):

Well masterContainer inside the string will do nothing. I think it should be:

```
$(masterContainer).find(':last-child');
```

Also note that `experimentOne('#experimentOne');` will send a string not a jQuery object. That would require `experimentOne($('#experimentOne'));`, which would leave:

```
experimentOne($('#experimentOne'));

   function experimentOne(masterContainer) {
   var experimentOneMenuButton = masterContainer.find(':last-child');
   // Note the lack of jQuery wrapper around masterContainer in this version
```

Depends on whether you want to force a jQuery object in the parameter or in the function itself!

Answer (score 0):

Your concatenation is wrong. Try that way:
`$(masterContainer + ' :last-child')`